# Haskell nested lists with newtype

Tags: haskell

Disclaimer: I am new to working with haskell.

I am working with proving logical formulas in haskell. I have trouble understanding how to work with `newtype`s and `data`s properly.

I have defined the following types to represent logical formulas that have the structure: `(a or b or c) and (d or e) and (f)` etc.

```hs
data Literal x = Literal x | Negation x
  deriving (Show, Eq)

newtype Or x = Or [Literal x]
  deriving (Show, Eq)

newtype And x = And [Or x]
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I want to write a function that can filter on the literals (i.e. take out certain `a` `b` or `c` based on some condition). Naively I thought this should be similar to filtering on `[[Literal x]]` but I cannot seem to get it to work.

My current method is something like:

```hs
filterLit :: Eq x => And x -> And x
filterLit = map (\(Or x) -> (filter (\(Lit l) -> condition l) x))
```

This doesn't type. I feel like I'm missing some syntax rules here. Let me know if you have suggestions on how I should approach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\(Or x) -> filter (\(Lit l) -> condition l) x
```

Let's check the type of this function.

The domain must have type `Or x`. That's OK.

The codomain is the result of `filter`, hence it is a list. Let's only write `[....]` for that.

Hence, the function is `Or x -> [....]`.

If we `map` that, we get `[Or x] -> [[....]]`. This is not the same as the claimed type `And x -> And x` -- a type error is raised.

First, you want your lambda to have type `Or x -> Or x`. For that, you can use `\(Or x) -> Or (filter .....)`.

Then, you want `filterLit` to be something like

```
filterLit (And ys) = And (map ....)
```

so that it has the right type.